# A component required a bean named 'dataSource' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am developing a simple Spring Batch jar using Spring Boot. I have used Configuration class to create dataSource bean and also annotated with @Component. But when I run the application using CommandLine Runner, it throws bean not found exception while reading the ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml.

I have did a little research of this error in google and found a solution, I have added below line in my ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.abp.printbatch"></context:component-scan>
```

**Adding this line has fixed the issue but has other side effects**

1. Spring is loading twice and all the spring core beans are getting instantiated twice. 
   I found this by checking the logs. Below logs for reference which shows same lines twice .
2. Spring JPA SQL statements are not showing up in the console even after adding spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true in the application-dev.properties.

is there a way to instantiate spring only once by removing the component scan in the xml and also fix the datasource bean not found issue. Please guide me. below log for your reference which clearly shows spring is loading twice.

```
    2020-05-23 16:04:06.976  INFO 90732 --- [           main] c.a.p.FileUploadApplication : Starting FileUploadApplication on MW7CH1-FZXX with PID 90732 (C:\gitforABP\SpringBatch\target\classes started by cac6584 in C:\gitforABP\SpringBatch)
2020-05-23 16:04:06.979  INFO 90732 --- [           main] c.a.p.FileUploadApplication : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-05-23 16:04:07.672  INFO 90732 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-23 16:04:07.752  INFO 90732 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 69ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.

2020-05-23 16:04:08.161  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-23 16:04:08.165  WARN 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-05-23 16:04:08.819  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Receiver class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getNetworkTimeout()I of interface java.sql.Connection.)
2020-05-23 16:04:08.870  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-23 16:04:08.923  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-23 16:04:09.006  INFO 90732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-23 16:04:09.152  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-23 16:04:09.312  INFO 90732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2020-05-23 16:04:10.351  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-23 16:04:10.364  INFO 90732 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-23 16:04:10.771  INFO 90732 --- [           main] c.a.p.FileUploadApplication : Started FileUploadApplication in 4.167 seconds (JVM running for 5.839)
2020-05-23 16:04:10.772  INFO 90732 --- [           main] c.a.p.FileUploadApplication : Local
2020-05-23 16:04:11.186  INFO 90732 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-23 16:04:11.206  INFO 90732 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 19ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.

2020-05-23 16:04:11.298  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2020-05-23 16:04:11.298  WARN 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-05-23 16:04:11.663  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-2 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Receiver class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getNetworkTimeout()I of interface java.sql.Connection.)
2020-05-23 16:04:11.691  INFO 90732 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2020-05-23 16:04:11.706  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-23 16:04:11.714  INFO 90732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2020-05-23 16:04:12.150  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-23 16:04:12.151  INFO 90732 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-23 16:04:12.170  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2020-05-23 16:04:12.264  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-05-23 16:04:12.465  WARN 90732 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs
2020-05-23 16:04:12.467  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2020-05-23 16:04:12.467  INFO 90732 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
```

**Entry Point**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abp.printbatch")
public class FileUploadApplication extends PrintBatchConstants implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private NotifyYaml notify;

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(FileUploadApplication.class);

        application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        application.run(args);

    }

      @Override 
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

      logger.info(notify.getEnvironment());


      ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
          "ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml", "AgencyBillPayAppConfig.xml" );



          JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class); 
          Job job=ctx.getBean(Job.class);

          jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
                  .addString(documentClass,"InvoiceStatementDocumentation")
                  .addString(type, "2040-09-13")
                  .addString(emailID, notify.getSupportEmailId())
                  .addString(environment, notify.getEnvironment())
                  .toJobParameters());

        ctx.close();

          System.exit(0);
      }

     }
```

**f**

```
package com.abp.printbatch.config;

@Configuration
@Component
public class DBConfig {


    @Bean
    @Primary
     public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").url("removed")
               .username("removed").password("removed").build();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove @Component annotation from the DBConfig.
Set the log level of the spring jpa higher.
You have 2 app context, because spring boot set one, and you set another when create new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext .

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you should not be using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`; Boot's job is to manage the context for you. Read the Getting Started Guides for examples on how to write a `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: Hi Zlaval, 

I have removed @Component from DBConfig and also removed component scan from ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml. I get the same error back again.

Comment: Hi  chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic, 

I have added ClassPathXMLApplicationContext  to instantiate job Launcher . 
To instantiate, I need the ClassPathXMLApplicationContext object. Without doint this, there is no way for me to start the joblauncher inside run method of my FileUploadApplication.class which implements CommandLineRunner interface. Please let me know if there is anyotherway to start the job launcher without instantiating ClassPathXMLApplicationContext.

Comment: Also what version of java and jdbc driver do you use?
"T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getNetworkTimeout()I of interface java.sql.Connection."

Java 7 add this two method to the interface, but it seems your jdbc driver is older.

Comment: Hi Zlaval,

I use OJDBC6-11.2.03 Jar and Java 8, Iam confused on how my question is related to JDBC driver . can you please clarify

Comment: As i mentioned, you have 2 app context, because you create a new one. You can use the context, boot creates to you (just inject it)

Comment: 'Iam confused on how my question is related to JDBC driver . can you please clarify' :
See the log you show us. There is a hikari log, your driver is not implements those methods, its because you use a driver compiled with java 6.

Comment: Hi Zlaval,  Thanks I got your point now. I am using java 8 in my build path, are you referring I need to get latest version of OJDBC from maven repository. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, I have imported the xmls during app startup and removed application context initialization inside the run method. Also I removed component scan inside XML. This has fixed both datasource not found issue and Show SQL issue. Now application is working as expected. Below is my new entry point class. Thanks for all your help :)

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abp.printbatch")
@ImportResource( { "ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml", "AgencyBillPayAppConfig.xml" } ) 
public class FileUploadApplication extends PrintBatchConstants implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private NotifyYaml notify;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(FileUploadApplication.class);

        application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        application.run(args);

    }

      @Override 
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

      logger.info(notify.getEnvironment());

          ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
          "ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml", "AgencyBillPayAppConfig.xml" );



        JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class); 
        Job job=ctx.getBean(Job.class);

         jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
          .addString(documentClass,"InvoiceStatementDocumentation") .addString(type,
          "2040-09-13") .addString(emailID, notify.getSupportEmailId())
          .addString(environment, notify.getEnvironment()) .toJobParameters());

          ctx.close();

          System.exit(0);
      }

     }
```